# WordPress site sends email from strange domains

Tags: email, dns, wordpress, domain

I had a WordPress site with a security plugin configured to send me periodical database backups via email. This morning I noticed that I was receiving these emails as coming from two strange domains I don't own nor recognize (the addresses were of a form similar to: wordpress@strangedomain.com , wordpress@fakedomain.org ). I panicked and decided to delete the site, as it was just a "staging" or backup site for my main site. However, I have looked up these two strange domains in whatsmydns.net, and they point to my server ip (a Digital Ocean droplet); and when I browse to these domains, my main site shows up. I don't how could this happen, and what the implications are. Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: I guess we need to know what *strangedomain* and *fakedomain* actually are, in order to give meaningful answers - i.e. someone might recognize them.

Comment: It could be related to configuration of hosting environment by your hosting provider.